# how to reload controller cache class in guard-spork with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want testing my contoller with guard-spork with rspec. When I modify my controller class. rpsec didn't reload my controller code. I think there is a reload or class cache problem.  After search some article, including put `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear` to `spec_helper` `each_run` and `prefork`. But not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Spork.each_run do
  # reload all the controllers
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/**/*.rb"].each do |controller|
    load controller
  end
end
```